# Вылетает приложение при попытке доступа к SharedPreference из BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcast-receiver

Вообщем, такая проблема, решил было сделать себе приложение, суть которого проста - есть 3 поля для ввода 3 параметров, а именно - API, Key и Numbers. Для ловли смс нашел примерчик в интернете. Все вставил, работало. Так как BroadcastReceiver находится в отдельном файле, было сложно найти хоть что-то, что помогло бы передать 3 параметра в файл с ловителем смс. Наткнулся на SharedPreference и используя пример попытался передать данные в ресивер. Оформил передачу в референсы тестового числа из onCreate. Студио все билдит, но при получении СМС приложение вылетает. Код ошибки:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ru.loreinc.smshandler, PID: 2615
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver ru.loreinc.smshandler.MyReceiver: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7d8a2d7f
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1672)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7d8a2d7f
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:339)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:304)
        at ru.loreinc.smshandler.MyReceiver.onReceive(MyReceiver.kt:46)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3187)
```

**----------------**

MainActivity.kt:

```
package ru.loreinc.smshandler

import android.Manifest
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences? = null
    var ed: SharedPreferences.Editor? = null

    val PREF = "myprefs"
    val COLOR_PREF = "colorPref"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ed = sharedPrefs?.edit();
        ed?.putInt(COLOR_PREF, 88005553535.toInt());
        ed?.apply();
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS)) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS), MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECEIVE_SMS)
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        when (requestCode) {
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECEIVE_SMS -> {
                if (grantResults.size > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "SMS permission granted. \nApp is ready for use.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "SMS permission denied. \nApp can't work without it.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECEIVE_SMS = 0
    }

    fun startApp(view: View?) {
        ed?.putInt(COLOR_PREF, 88005553535.toInt());
        ed?.apply();
    }
}
```

MyReceiver.kt:

```
package ru.loreinc.smshandler

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Build
import android.telephony.SmsMessage
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast



class MyReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    var msg: String? = null
    var phoneNo: String? = ""
    var sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences? = null
    var ed: SharedPreferences.Editor? = null

    val PREF = "myprefs"
    val COLOR_PREF = "colorPref"



    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        Log.i(TAG, "Intent Received: " + intent.action)
        if (intent.action === SMS_RECEIVED) {
            val dataBundle = intent.extras
            if (dataBundle != null) {
                val mypdu = dataBundle["pdus"] as Array<*>?
                val message = arrayOfNulls<SmsMessage>(mypdu!!.size)
                for (i in mypdu.indices) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        val format = dataBundle.getString("format")
                        message[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(mypdu[i] as ByteArray, format)
                    } else {
                        message[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(mypdu[i] as ByteArray)
                    }
                    msg = message[i]?.getMessageBody()
                    phoneNo = message[i]?.getOriginatingAddress()
                }

                val theme = sharedPrefs!!.getInt(COLOR_PREF, 0)
                Toast.makeText(context, theme, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            }
        }
    }




    companion object {
        private const val SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"
        private const val TAG = "SmsBroadcastReceiver"
    }
}
```

Ребят, молю вас, помогите. Все нервы на этот Android Studio исчерпал, уж очень сложно найти нормальные примеры того, что мне необходимо. Я не прошу вас сделать все за меня, просто ткните меня носов в ошибку и помогите ее решить :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toast.makeText(context, theme, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

theme - инт?

мб там стринга нужна?

Comment: боже, такая маленькая ошибка и столько трепала нервы... Спасибо за помощь! Теперь все работает!